# Постоянная проверка интернета

Tags: java, android

Как в приложениях делают проверку интернета? Т.е. если нету или пропадает интернет в ходе работы приложения, то нужно вывести сообщение. Как это реализовать?

Comment: посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев абсолютно бессмысленно проверять наличие/отсутствие интернета, так как во время проверки он может быть, а во время сетевого взаимодействия интернет может отвалиться.

Как правило, в подобных ситуациях просто отлавливают экзэпшены, которые могут возникнуть во время работы с интернетом, и от них уже крутятся.

Но если Вы очень хотите проверить состояние сетевого подключения, то можете просто сделать условный пинг до двух-трех серверов с высоким аптаймом.

Анализ системных броадкастов (без дополнительных манипуляций) в общем случае не поможет, так как устройство может находиться в какой-либо Wi-Fi-сети, однако из самой сети интернет может быть недоступен.

Comment: Стоит делать пинг в момент получения события. Если делать его постоянно, батарейки на долго не хватит.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую не множить костыли и читать официальную документацию [определение наличия подключения к интернету](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html?hl=ru)

Таким образом sdk предоставляет нам класс `ConnectivityManager` который:

- Осуществляет мониторинг сетевых подключений (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS и т. Д.)
- Отправляет широковещательные сообщения при изменении подключения к сети
- Позволяет переподключаться в другую сеть, когда потеряна связь с текущей сетью
- Предоставляет API, который позволяет приложениям ***запрашивать состояние доступных сетей***.
- Предоставляет API, который позволяет приложениям запрашивать и выбирать сети для их отправки и получения трафика.

В простейшем сценарии узнать, доступна ли сеть можно вот так:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```